# SQL trigger - nesting INSERT INTO in IF condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create trigger registring in new table employees whom salary is being raised above 5000 and didn't get salary higher than 5000 so far.

Trigger I wrote is returning error `Error(2,41): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here`.

Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_gotrich_trig BEFORE UPDATE OF salary ON employees
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF :NEW.salary>5000 AND :OLD.salary<=5000 THEN
        INSERT INTO emp_gotrich VALUES (employee_id, SYSDATE, :OLD.salary, :NEW.salary);
    END IF;
END;
```

And here's `emp_gotrich` table:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_gotrich ( emp_id NUMBER(6), raise_date DATE, old_sal NUMBER(8,2), new_sal NUMBER(8,2) );
```

I guess that  `INSERT` statemet isn't nested properly but i don't know what should i change.

I also tried to use 'WHEN' but i dont know where should i omitt colons, so it doeasn't work too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_getrich_log BEFORE UPDATE OF salary ON employees FOR EACH ROW
WHEN
    NEW.salary>5000 AND OLD.salary<=5000;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO emp_gotrich VALUES(employee_id, SYSDATE, :OLD.salary, :NEW.salary);
END;
```

Please, help me find a way to run it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to specify `:OLD` or `:NEW` on the `employee_id` value in your INSERT statement. I believe it should be:

```
INSERT INTO emp_gotrich
  (EMP_ID, RAISE_DATE, OLD_SAL, NEW_SAL)
VALUES
  (:OLD.employee_id, SYSDATE, :OLD.salary, :NEW.salary);
```

I suggest that a field list, such as the one I added, should always be included in an INSERT statement.